# what is Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' ？

Tags: reactjs, typescript

code
board- part

```
export default function Chessboard(){
    let board = [];
    for(let i = 0 ; i < horizontalAxis.length; i++)
    {
        for(let j = verticalAxis.length-1 ; j >= 0 ; j--)
        {
            const num =  i + j + 2 ;
            board .push(<Tile number= { num} />);
        }
    }
    return <div id = "chessboard">{board}</div>
}
```

error by **board .push(<Tile number= { num} />);**
i dont know how to solve the problem?

tile part

```
interface props{
    number : number;
}

export default function tile ( {number} : props){
    if(number % 2 === 0)
    {
        return <div className="tile black-tile"></div>
    }
    else
    {
        return <div className="tile white-tile"></div>
    }
}
```

I don't know whats wrong?

How can I solve it? I'm the new guy for Ts, and I have googled it for long time but still don't know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```js
let board: JSX.Element[] = [];
```